HTML Templates Overlapping in Google Sheets
Previously, when I created two HTML templates, opening the second template would automatically close the previous one, ensuring that only one HTML template was visible on the screen at any time. However, with the latest update to Google Sheets, no matter how many HTML templates I create, all of them remain visible on the screen. How can I ensure that when a new HTML template is displayed, the previous ones are closed? Below are example codes and screenshots related to my issue.
Image
function showTemplate1() {
  var htmlOutput1 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page1')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput1, 'page1');  
  var htmlOutput2 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page2')
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput2, 'page2');
}

page1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<h4>This is Page1</h4>
<p>Goodbye World!</p>

  </body>
</html>

page2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<h4>This is Page2</h4>
<p>Goodbye World!</p>

  </body>
</html>

I was creating two HTML templates. When the second HTML template was opened, the first HTML template would automatically close.

I opened a ticket with google on this issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/356297568) and now the code works as before 26072024.

Yes, the problem is now solved.

I noticed the exact change but didn't find an announcement about it. As of July 26, 2024, there is no way to close a dialog using server-side code due to this change, but you can use client-side code.
Workaround
To automatically close a dialog on the client-side's JavaScript code use google.script.host.close().
The below code will close the dialog when the execution of a server-side function named doSomething finishes.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h4>This is Page1</h4>
    <p>Goodbye World!</p>
    <script>
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).doSomething();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

The following is just a server-side dummy function, included to make it clear the above code.
// Add this to a .gs file.
function doSomething(){
  Utilities.sleep(10000) // wait 10 seconds
}

To emulate the old behavior, instead of including the opening of both dialogs in the same function, use google.script.run to open the second dialog, then close the first.
function showTemplate1() {
  var htmlOutput1 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page1')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput1, 'page1');  
}

function showTemplate2(){
  var htmlOutput2 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page2')
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput2, 'page2');
}

page1
I'm including setTimeout to add a delay of 10 seconds before opening the second dialog to make it easier to observe the script behavior.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h4>This is Page1</h4>
    <p>Goodbye World!</p>
    <script>
       // Wait 10 seconds before opening the second dialog
       setTimeOut(() => { 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).showTemplate2();
         }, 10000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Related

Auto close modal dialog - After server code is done, close dialog in Google Spreadsheet
Auto close google app script dialog when processing is finished


I have the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802161/spreadsheetapp-getui-showmodaldialog-has-changed-since-26072024 . Since I am using only Google Sheets (i.e. not creating HTML templates as Halit is doing) am I shafted and there is no solution for my case?

@mortpiedra The template part is irrelevant. Both are using the SpreadsheetApp.showModalDialog / HtmlService.HtmlOutput. The issue is the same. The workaround should work too for your case.
