SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog has changed since 26072024
I have been using this code with GAS in Sheets to display two dialogs successfully for a long time:
function demo() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Patience!</b>'), 'Processing! Please wait');

//do some stuff

   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>'), 'Ready. Please continue');  
}

Since yesterday (26.07.2024) this code does not work (i.e. the first dialog does not close) as before which is described very well in this thread.
Hence, does anybody know if this is a permanent change or if it is a temporary glitch?
Is there any documentation anywhere describing this new behaviour?
My GAS skills are very basic and I do not understand how the solution/work around in the thread above can be applied to me since I am only using Google Sheets.
Back in the day I used to use this approach, but it sucked of course:
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Processing...", "Please WAIT!", 60); 

Since my productive application stopped running - i.e. the end users do not know how to cope - because of this change/bug I am a bit desperate and looking for a quick fix to solve this.
Additional information added 30072024: the script is executed through an onEdit-trigger. By using a barcode scanner which acts as HID (keyboard etc.) the end-user 'edits' the sheet and the script is triggered.
Just as a point of explanation why this functioanlity (as it worked up until 26072024) is so valuable: whilst a modal dialog box is open the sheet itself is 'greyed out' and the sheet cannot be edited from the screen where the modal box is open.
Thus, while the script is executing the modal dialog box is kept open to ensure that the content of the sheet is not edited from the screen where the modal box is open.
The last instruction in the script is to close the modal dialog box, thereby enabling the editing of the sheet again.
Bug reported to Google here.

The code works for me

@Cooper with 'works for me' you mean when you execute the second command, the first pop-up message is closed and only the second with the message 'Ready. Please continue' is open??? This is how it worked for me until Satruday (26072024), but since Saturday the first pop-up does not close.

The first one closed then second open.

@Cooper how can it be that it works for you, but not for me??? I am using EXACTLY the code for the function demo as above - nothing more nothing less - and the behaviour is not the same for us. Also Wicket experiences that it does not work for him any longer (as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78796911/html-templates-overlapping-in-google-sheets  ).

@mortpiedra You might have to edit the question to explain the issue better. In a comment to my answer, you mentioned your real case is executed by an onEdit trigger, but that, among other things, are not mentioned in the question.

@mortpiedra Perhaps it's because I don't use workspaces.  I don't really know

@Wicket your comments and suggestions are most appreciated: thank you!

I opened a ticket with google on this issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/356297568) and now the code works as before 26072024.

I opened a ticket with google on this issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/356297568) and now the code works as before 26072024.

If you want to tell the user that script execution ended, in this case, it is probably best to update the content of the first dialog instead of opening a second dialog, but this might require learning more things, specifically using client-side JavaScript to handle the Document Object Model (DOM) using document.querySelector, document.getElementById among other methods.
However, considering a notice shown to the user when a script is executed from a custom menu or by clicking an image with a script function assigned, you might better reconsider if the dialog is needed.
Here is the notice I'm talking about:


The difference between this question and the other is the way that the HtmlService.HtmlOutput required as the first parameter of SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog is handled. The other question uses HTML files, while this uses a string for the HtmlService.HtmlOutput content.
You should handle longer strings if you don't want to use an HTML file. Another option is to use the HtmlService.HtmlOutput.append method.
Example
I added some brake lines to make the code easier to read here. Also, I removed the script from the second dialog. Other than having google.script.host.close(), it will close the second dialog immediately, which is no longer "required" due to the "issue".
function demo() {
   const javascript = '<script>google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).doSomething();</script>';
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
      HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Patience!</b>')
     .append(javascript), 
     'Processing! Please wait'
   );

}

//do some stuff
function doSomething(){
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
      HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Add something to the dialog body'), 
      'Ready. Please continue'
   );  
}

Related

Auto close modal dialog - After server code is done, close dialog in Google Spreadsheet


Thank you for your answer @Wicket. The 'Running script' notice you mention is not displayed when the script runs in my application, I assume because the script is executed by an onEdit trigger (right?). The core requirement I have is that the end-user is BLOCKED/PREVENTED from accessing the sheet whilst the script is running. Up until 26072024 the 'SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService...' logic with the two dialogs have provided exactly this feature. I dont see how your 'Example' above solves my problem since the 2nd dialog ('Ready. Please continue') does not close automatically.

Right, triggers don't show the running script banner.

There is no 100% way to block a user from accessing the spreadsheet while a script is running other than changing the spreadsheet-sharing settings. The answer is not intended to "meet" your requirements. This is intended to explain what happens and how you could create something that meet them. Please see the question linked in the related section. Here is again for your convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32527682/1595451
